# Как перевести бинарное представление маски подсети в обычную и префиксную, с помощью утилит Linux?

Tags: сеть, подсети, маска

Нужно перевести бинарное представление маски подсети: 11111111.11111111.11111111.11000000, в десятичное представление и в префиксное. Пробовал использовать такие утилиты как: netmask, ipcalc, sipcalc, но в них либо отсутствует такой функционал, либо нет таких опций. Можно и перевести ручками или по таблице, но мне требуется через утилиту.

Comment: В смысле сделать из этого `/26`?

Comment: Да, как оказалось, ipcalc не может работать с бинарным представление маски подсети

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ipcalc` не может работать с бинарным представление маски подсети. Чтобы использовать такую маску в `ipcalc` придется перевести ее в префиксный вид или стандартный.